# could not load file or assembly 'log4net', 'crystaldecisions.reportappserver.clientdoc' in vs2017

Tags: crystal-reports, desktop-application, crystal-reports-viewer

I am getting title error when I am running project (desktop application) in vs2017.

The Project is first created in vs2012, while when I running the project in vs2017, it showing me crystalreport1 error.

I have tried many things like install sap crystal report for vs2017 and reference from nuget package but didnt work.

For more clear let see the image of the error

[image]

Whenever I am opening report windows form at that time it showing this error.

Thank You.